# MAMP Pro 3.1 phpMyAdmin dimmed unavailable

Tags: phpmyadmin, osx-mavericks, mamp-pro

After upgrade from 3.0 to MAMP Pro 3.1, the phpMyAdmin icon is dimmed unavailable.
Sequel Pro and MySQLWorkbench are alive. Mac OS X 10.9.5 working well.
This http://blog-en.mamp.info/2013/08/how-to-upgrade-phpmyadmin-in-mamp-mamp.html do not work too.
([see this image](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bz7L2Pl4PvsYaDkxbElMcTRrUlU/view?usp=sharing))
¿How to get phpMyAdmin available again?

Answer (score 0):

**PHP 5.3.x needed to use phpMyAdmin with MAMP Pro 3.1**

Here is the requirement:
clic WebStart icon, clic the link at "MySQL can be administered with phpMyAdmin."
you will see a page at url like this:
.../MAMP/index.php?page=phpmyadmin&language=(your-language) saying:
**PHP 5.3+ is required**